# renting, showing and returning a car arraylist not working properly

Tags: java, arraylist

Well basically I have an assignment that has to be done for January. I have to to create a mock rental service that allow customers to rent cars. I am basing the logic off of an ArrayList, using its methods to manage my car collection.

I have some problems with my code, the logic in a lot of my methods is not working correctly. In the code sample I included the `showCar`, `rentTheCar` and `returnCar` methods  are not working as they should. The `showCar` method displays all the cars, although when invoking the method it asks me for the `carNumber`. The `rentThecar` and `returnCar` seem to be renting/returning all cars, instead of just the one I specify.

I am showing relevant code from my classes below, if anyone can help me figure out where I might have gone wrong.Please I want to make it clear that i do not want my homework done just some guidance. Thanks.

Show car method:

```
public void showCar (int carNumber)
{

    if (cars.size() < 0 ) {
        System.out.println ("Add cars first!!!");
    }
    else if (carNumber < cars.size()) {
        System.out.println(cars.get(carNumber));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error!! This note cannot be shown, because it does not exist!!");
    }
}
```

Rent car method:

```
public void rentTheCar (int carNumber, String CustomerName, String hireDate, String returnDate, int daysOfHire)
{

    if (cars.size() < 0) {
       System.out.println("Empty list!! Add cars first!!");
    }
    else if (carNumber > cars.size()) {
       System.out.println("This car does not exist!!");
    }
    else {
        for (Car car : cars) {
            int index = 0;
            cars.get (carNumber);
            car.rentTheCar(CustomerName, hireDate, returnDate, daysOfHire);
            index ++;
        }
    } 
}
```

Return car method:

```
public void returnCar (int carNumber)
{
    cars.get(carNumber);
    if (cars.size() < 0) {
       System.out.println("Error!! It is impossible to return a car from an empty list");
    }
    else if (carNumber > cars.size()) {
        System.out.println("Error!! Not a valis car!!");
    }
    else {
        for (Car car : cars) {
            car.returnTheCar();
            System.out.println ("The car has been returned correctly");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the list is empty, then it has size 0. I'd write cars.size() <= 0. Also lists are zero indexed, so it should be "carNumber >= cars.size()".

Answer (score 1):

So what is the purpose of the for loops in ReturnCar and RentTheCar?

What are they doing?

The above clue should put you on the right track.

Comment: Hey, thenk you very much for your response! I created a car class previously, there is two methods in that class called rentTheCar and returnCar. The first one takes parameters as the name of the customer and dates of hire and return and the days of hire and then sets a boolean to onLoan = true. The returnCar just returns the car and the parameters entered previously when renting the car to "" any string, 0 any int and false the boolean. the purpose of the arraylist is to do the same however just creating the cars directly from the arraylist instead of creating and object car everytime.

Comment: I know why you've got an array, given your stated problem is rentthe car is being called for all cars, and you are calling it inside the loop.....

Answer (score 0):

Your `showCar` method looks fine, are you sure its showing all the cars in your collection? As far as your other two methods, you are looping over your entire collection and calling your rental operation on each element. You are basing your entire logic off indexed arrays, so use your index.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

```
add(int index, E element) 
          Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).

get(int index) 
          Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
```

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your response, basically the show car is showing me just a number and basically I want it to show me the description of the car but what it is showing me is a number like this Car@67f31652.

Comment: Your seeing the output from the default `toString()` method on java.lang.Object. If you want to see something more descriptive then override `toString()` in your Car object and make it return something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at your foreach loop, maybe you will find a hint or two there! This line:

```
for (Car car : cars) {
    // do something...
}
```

There is a reason why it is called a for-**each** loop. :)
Hope I helped.

Comment: hey! Thanks for your response, i know what you mean now! :) you actually did help me! I am making for every car in that class to do the same!(if that makes sense) :) Thanks!!!